# Javascript- Arrays with tokens that are a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, token, tokenize

Let's say I have the array `['dcab', 'feac', 'gwad', 'dnae']` but want to make it so that each `'a'` is in its own token, eg `['dc', 'a', 'b', 'fe', 'a', 'c', 'gw', 'a', 'd', 'dn', 'a', 'e'];`. How would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Huh?  How are you getting that result?  How do you know where to split it?  Why do some elements have 2 letters and others have one?

Comment: What do you have so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Rocket, they have two letters because I want the a to be separated, in it's own "token"  so that means the text before and after the a also go in it's own token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var arr = ['dcab', 'feac', 'gwad', 'dnae'];
var result = [];
var i;
var s;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    s = arr[i].split('a');
    result.push(s[0]);
    if (s.length > 1) {
        result.push('a');
        result.push(s[1]);
    }
}
```

Only works if each string contains exactly one or zero 'a' characters. You could iterate through the result of split if it could contain more.

Comment: thanks so much for this. If you don't mind, can you please quickly explain your code though? I thought running a split would delete all of the "a"'s from the array

Comment: what if there are multiple `a`s in a string? you probably need an inner loop.

Comment: sure. `split` returns an array of string parts separated by 'a'. It will return an array with only one element if there is no 'a'. no matter what, we keep that first element. Then, if an 'a' was found (s has more than one element), we add that to the result, then we add the next part of the string. This occurs once for each element of the given array.

Comment: @Robert, I mentioned that just below the code. I didn't want to make it unnecessarily complex since that condition wasn't present in the given example. I figured that handling the non-present delimiter was already more than he asked for.

Comment: Hey, no worries. We all want to be thoroughly correct here, and you were just working towards that end.

Answer (score 8):

```
var x = ['dcab', 'feac', 'gwad', 'dnae'];
x = x.join('-').replace(/a/g,"-a-").split('-');
```

---

**Update:** As @Robert pointed out, if you have `'a'` at the beginning or end, this will cause `''` blank strings to appear in the final array. You can fix this by doing the following to remove the blank strings:

```
x.join('-').replace(/a/g,"-a-").split('-').filter(function(x) { return x!='' });
```

Or, for larger arrays where performance might be an issue, you can simply get rid of the extra delimiters using another `.replace()` (this is probably the better approach, though it isn't as readable):

```
x.join('-').replace(/a/g,"-a-").replace(/^\-|\-(?=\-)|\-$/g,'').split('-');
```

Of course, it goes without saying that your delimiter can be anything (it doesn't have to be a `'-'`) once you can guarantee that this won't be in any of your strings.

Comment: The join should be '-' not '' I think.

Comment: ...That's an awesome little one-liner :-)

Comment: I like this solution, nice and small.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if one of the strings starts or ends with "a" or contains multiple successive "a"s.

Comment: @robert True, thanks for pointing that out, I didn't consider all the cases it seems. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Oh, great. I read the question more carefully now. Actually it's just about how to process this very specific array. So I don't really think that Kpower was interested in a fully working general algorithm. Anyway I think your updated version will work fine with those special cases I mentioned. But what if the original array contained empty strings? They wouldn't appear in the result anymore. All depends on the specification of those arrays probably. The question doesn't even say that the array only contains strings. :D

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = ['dcab', 'feac', 'gwad', 'dnae'];

var new_arr = arr.reduce(function(ret, val) {
    ret.push.apply(ret, val.split(/(a)/))
    return ret;
}, []);
```

Note that capturing and retaining the split character isn't supported in some older browsers.

---

A little more concise like this...

```
var new_arr = arr.reduce(function(ret, val) {
    return ret.concat(val.split(/(a)/));
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks @Rocket. I thought I had seen that value in the result.

Comment: I think he wants to use 'a' as a delimiter, but +1 because reduce isn't used enough.

Comment: Thanks! Um, just curious though how does the whole ret and val thing work?

Comment: ...in other words, the first argument to the callback is an *"accumulator"*, and the second argument is the value of the current item in the iteration. The "accumulator" is the return value of the last iteration. If you were summing the values in an Array of numbers, you could seed it with `0`, then do `return ret + val`. Each new iteration, `ret` will be the previous return value *(the current sum)*, so it accumulates the sum of all the items in the array. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YV8kK/)

Comment: Well, but couldn't you make it even more concise by first joining all the strings and then calling split only once?

Comment: @Robert: I chose to show `.reduce` solutions, as it can be helpful if the requirements change to require more detailed manipulation. The trouble with joining the entire string, is that you lose the original separation between the words. You'd need to join with some designated token, then include that token in the split, and clean up the array after. Like this `['dcab', 'feac', 'gwad', 'dnae'].join('~~~').split(/~~~|(a)/);`, and then cleaning up the `undefined` array members that were inserted.

Comment: Oooh, I see. sorry. I forgot about the original separation problem. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

First you treat the array elements separately and extract their tokens. Then you combine the results.

There are 3 types of token you are looking for:

- a single "a". The regular expression for that is `/a/`.
- a sequence of other characters => `/[^a]+/`
- when the original element is an empty string you want to keep that => `/^$/`

So in total the regular expression for a token is `/a|[^a]+|^$/`. For extracting *all* tokens you need to include the global search flag `g`.

```
var strings = ['dcab', 'feac', 'gwad', 'dnae'];

var arrays = strings.map(function(string) {
    return string.match(/[^a]+|a|^$/g);
});
```

`match` returns an array with the tokens it found in the string. All that is left to do is to concatenate all of those arrays.

Luckily there is an array method just for this specific purpose. But unfortunately it isn't exactly easy to use with an unknown number of arrays:

```
var tokens = arrays[0].concat(arrays[1], arrays[2], ...
```

First of all you don't know how many arrays you have. So there's no way the pass the correct number of arguments. But maybe you don't even know if `array[0]` exists. So you would better use an empty array as the starting point.

There are ways to solve this problem though.

One solution is to divide the concatenations into multiple steps:

```
var tokens = arrays.reduce(function(result, array) {
    return result.concat(array);
}, []); // note the initial empty array
```

But to me it seems more appropriate to make use of `apply` and pass all arrays at once:

```
var concat = Array.prototype.concat;
var tokens = concat.apply([], arrays);
```

All put together the code would look like this:

```
var strings = ['dcab', 'feac', 'gwad', 'dnae'];
var concat = Array.prototype.concat;

var tokens = concat.apply([], strings.map(function(string) {
    return string.match(/[^a]+|a|^$/g);
}));
```